# fancybox 3 change scrollbar of thumbs from x-axis to y-axis when the device is >800

Tags: fancybox-3

I'm using fancybox 3 (version 3.3.5) it's working perfect.

I have also changed the position of the thumbs from Vertical (y-axis) to Horizontal (x-axis). This is also working good.

But, when I go to a smaller device (<800) the thumbs are Vertical (y-axis) which is good, but the scrollbar stays at the bottom and is not Vertical.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not possible to automatically switch axis, it would be best to simply check screen dimensions before applying your modifications.